# OnBackPressedCallback() using OnBackPressedDispatcher() does not work

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, onbackpressed

I opened the `dialog fragment` by clicking on the `recycler view item` implemented in the activity.

And for the `back function` I used `onBackPressedCallback()`.

However, I tried to display a `toast message` for testing, but nothing happens.

I referred this to the Android developer documentation.

What is the problem?

***WC.java (DialogFragment)***

```
public class WritingCommentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements CommentModel.EditInputListener {
    OnBackPressedCallback callback;
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_writing_comment_dialog, container, false);
        bindViews(view);
        addCommentItem();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onCreateView()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return view;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        callback =  new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        callback.remove();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setDialogSize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149173280#comment2):

> Dialogs are separate windows that always sit above your activity's window. This means that the dialog will continue to intercept the system back button no matter what state the underlying FragmentManager is in, or what code you run in your Activity's `onBackPressed()` - which is where the `OnBackPressedDispatcher` plugs into.

You'd see the same issue if you were to put this code in your Activity's `onBackPressed()` - the Activity is no longer the window receiving key events (of which the system back button is one of them), so it is expected that anything that plugs into that is not triggered.

The only place that receives the call to the system back button when a Dialog is open is the Dialog's [`onBackPressed()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#onBackPressed()), which would mean creating your own subclass of `Dialog` (rather than relying on `super.onCreateDialog()`) and manually overriding that method.

Of course, if you just want a callback for when the dialog is closed (i.e., the default behavior for the system back button when a dialog is open), then you'd want to override the `DialogFragment`'s [`onCancel()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#onCancel(android.content.DialogInterface)).

Comment: 1.It's a little difficult. So what's the difference between onCancel() and onBackPressed()? Aren't both methods that occur when the dialog is closed after opening?
2.Does the word `rather than relying on` mean not to use `DialogFragment` and inherit `Diaog`?

Comment: `onCancel()` means the dialog is already on its way out and you can't stop it from happening. Overriding `onBackPressed()` gives you a choice to **not** call `super.onBackPressed()`, which is useful if you want to do something *other* than close the dialog when the system back button is pressed. What I'm saying is that you can't rely on the plain old `Dialog` created by `super.onCreateDialog()` - you'd need to instead create a new instance of your custom subclass. You'd still need to use `DialogFragment`.

Comment: So the first answer is that if I define an event when the `dialog closes`, I don't have to use `onBackPressed()` or `onBackPressedCallback()`, right?
And the second answer... I'm sorry, but I didn't get it right.
I don't understand how to redefine `onBackpressed()` using a custom subclass of instance.

Comment: If you want to keep the default behavior of the system back button to close the dialog, then `onBackPressed()` and `onBackPressedCallback()` were never the right choice, that's correct. You'd just want to override `onCancel()` in your `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to you, you solved the problem well!